# slow GROUP_CONCAT in sub query

Tags: mysql

have a sub query which uses GROUP_CONCAT to group results in one field.
but the query takes 3 secs to run with this and 0.05secs without.
I have indexed accessory.actionid and action.actionid is PK.
Is there a solution to improve performance?

```
SELECT
  action.actiondate, acc.acc, acc.acccount
FROM
  `action`
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT 
    actionid,
    GROUP_CONCAT(accessory) AS acc,
    COUNT(actionid) AS acccount
  FROM
  accessorieslink 
  GROUP BY actionid) AS acc 
  ON acc.actionid = action.actionid
```

Comment: Does the performance degrade from just the group_concat line or the whole accessorieslink subquery?

Comment: seems to be concat line only - when taken out the query runs fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off using this:

```
SELECT
    a.actiondate, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(al.accessory,'') ) as acc, 
    SUM(IF(al.actionid IS NULL,0,1)) as acccount
FROM
  `action` a
LEFT JOIN accessorieslink al
    ON al.actionid = a.actionid
GROUP BY
    a.actionid
ORDER BY 
    NULL
```

Comment: glad to hear it :) do not forget to accept the answer you think suits you best

Answer (score 1):

because you are making alias of group_concat same as the table `acc` which cause mysql to think.

change one of the aliace names.

```
   GROUP_CONCAT(accessory) AS acc,
                               ^^^--//------ this
```

and

```
  GROUP BY actionid) AS acc 
                        ^^--// and this
```